# How to use environment specific firebase configs to initialize firebase app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a react application with two firebase configs, one for staging environment and one for prod environment.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

const prodFirebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-----------------------------",
    authDomain: "-----------------------------",
    databaseURL: "-----------------------------",
    projectId: "-----------------------------",
    storageBucket: "-----------------------------",
    messagingSenderId: "-----------------------------",
    appId: "-----------------------------",
    measurementId: "-----------------------------"
  }
```

Now, I want something like when I am deploying my app to production I should initialize my app with production config else with staging config.

```
// Something like this
    if(env === 'prod') {
    const myFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(prodFirebaseConfig );
    } else {
    const myFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
```

It's like app which is running on staging environment should use staging firebase and one which is running on production should use prod firebase. I am using webpack to build files.

I am new to firebase, any help regarding best way to manage this and multiple deployments would be appreciated.

Thanks